# Chamar funções usando botões

Tags: python, if, for

No código abaixo criei uma interface gráfica com alguns botões, porém quando clico nos botões eles não chamam a função.
Não achei o erro, peço ajuda.

```
# Importando a biblioteca tkinter
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

def abre(j):
    if (j==1):
        lbr['text'] = 'Clicou no Primeiro'
    elif(j==2):
         lbr['text'] = 'Clicou no Segundo'




# Criando a janela principal
janela = Tk()
janela.geometry('600x600+150+150')
janela.state('zoomed')
janela.title ('DESENVOLVIMENTO DE SISTEMA COMPLETO II')

# para desabilitar botão state=DISABLED

# Gerando os botôes
rotulo =('Primeiro','Segundo','Terceiro','Quarto','Quinto')
k = 180
j=0
for i in rotulo:
        j += 1
        bt = Button(janela, command=(abre(j)), width=20, height=2, anchor='center',font=("Helvetica", 12) , text=(i),bg='#696969', fg='#FFA500')
        bt.place(x=k,y=2)
        k += 200

lbr = Label(janela,text='Teste dos botões')
lbr.place(x=200,y=200)


# Término do sistema.
janela.mainloop()
```

Comment: Olá @José Alves, favor testar a minha resposta. Se estiver de acordo peço por gentileza que marque como certa. Se precisar de ajuda estou a disposição. Abraço!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tentei manter o máximo do teu código. Basicamente eu criei a função `exbir_botao` que recebe como parâmetros `var` que é um valor do `dict rotulo` e `x` que será utilizado para determinar onde o botão será exibido. No `while` eu percorro o dicionário, incremento `x` e chamo a função para exibir o botão.

Segue o código:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

# Dicionario com os rótulos dos botões

rotulo = {1:'Primeiro', 2:'Segundo', 3:'Terceiro', 4:'Quarto', 5:'Quinto'}


# Criando a janela principal

janela = Tk()
janela.geometry('600x600+150+150')
janela.state('zoomed')
janela.title ('DESENVOLVIMENTO DE SISTEMA COMPLETO II')


msg = "Teste do botão: "

lbr = Label(janela,text=msg)

lbr.place(x=200,y=200)


# Altera a mensagem no label (var é um value do dict rotulo) 
def exibir_msg(var):    
    lbr.config(text=msg+var)


# Criar o botão com o text retirado do dicionário rotulo e exibi-lo na janela na posição especificada por x
def exbir_botao(var, x):    
    botao = Button(janela, text=var, command=lambda:exibir_msg(var),
                   width=20, height=2, anchor='center',font=("Helvetica", 12),
                   bg='#696969', fg='#FFA500')    
    botao.place(x=x,y=2)


x = 180 # posição inicial de variável x do primeiro botão

for k in rotulo: # note que k é a chave do dicionario rotulo 

    var = rotulo.get(k)

    exbir_botao(var, x)

    x += 200 # incrementando x em 200  


janela.mainloop()
```

Comment: Entendi e seu código ficou bem mais inteligente que o meu. Poderia indicar onde estava o erro no meu código? grato.

Comment: 1) Por exemplo, a tua função `abre`  fez uma referência para a label `lbr` antes de declara-la.
2) O `rotulo` você declarou como tupla, enquanto que seria mais fácil usar um dicionário que permite recuperar um valor indexado a uma chave. 3) A declaração do Button você fez dentro do laço `for` passava a impressão que estava correto porque os botões eram criados no locais especificados, mas como você estava sempre atribuindo a declaração do botão a variável `bt` ...

Comment: ... (na mesma variável) o que aconteceu foi que no final do loop todos os botões eram na verdade um “eco” do mesmo botão (`bt`) onde estava sendo atualizado apenas a propriedade `text`, porém a propriedade `command` ficou sempre se a mesma. 4) Por fim repare que no `import` eu deixo explicito que estou importando Tk, Label, Button do módulo tkinter. Espero ter sido claro.